# Buttons inline block using bootstrap grid system to a certain px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have four buttons using bootstrap inline block until size 768px. At 1199 they fall underneath each other but I want them to stay spaced out and not fall underneath each other until 768px.

How do I keep them side by side under 1200px? Mine automatically fall underneath at 1199px.

```
<div id="searchoptions">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn-u,.btn-group {
        width:100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1199px){
    .btn-u {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `col-sm-3` instead...

```
    <div id="searchoptions">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="accountNumber" name="accountNumber">PROPERTY ID</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="name" name="name">OWNER NAME</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="location" name="location">PROPERTY ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-default margin-bottom-10" id="billingAddress" name="billingAddress">BILLING ADDRESS</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/mbCCxpDjrK

Comment: i do this but the inbetween space between the buttons does not come out even then

Comment: from like 970 to 780px the last two buttons are super close but the first two are not when i use that

Comment: like in your example when you shrink the size down do you see how the last two buttons get really close and the front two stay far apart right before they drop down below each other

Comment: upvoted because it is super close to what I am trying to do. Thank you for answering

Comment: yeah, since the grid columns are equal width it's really not meant for this scenario

Comment: is there a better way to do that?